# Am i accessing wrong (out of bounds) char array Index in c

Tags: c, arrays, null, indexing, int

Suppose we have a character array in c like,

```
char a[20];
```

Can we access index 20 to put terminating NULL like this.

```
a[20]='\0';
```

But in my algo. ("which is integer to char array converter") this is necessary to put terminating NULL if last index is,smaller then the size of char array for example,

If size of my int is 4 ("1421")  then i have to put '1' at index 0, '4' at index 1, '2' at index 2 and '1' at index 3.

And finally terminating NULL at index 4

```
index=4;
a[index]='\0';
```

Another way to fix the same code,

```
if(index<20)  (Will increase one condition)
    a[index]='\0';
```

But i just wanna know is it possible......to put terminating NULL at index 20.

**OK I GOT THIS** EVERYONE THANK-U VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: You don't "own" index 20... your 20 element array only goes to 19!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array `char a[20]` has space for 20 characters, at indexes 0 through 19. Writing to `a[20]` is writing outside the array and will have unpredictable consequences. You are limited to 20 characters *including any terminating* NULL character. If you need space for 20 characters plus a terminating NULL, you need to declare your array as `char a[21];`. Also, declaring `a[20]` does not put a NULL anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`char a[20]` : 20 means you can have elements from `0-19` . and it's assumed that you will use only upto 19.if you fill upto 20 then you will get an error.

change it to :

`a[20+1] => a[21]` now you can use 20 to put `\0` . `a[20]='\0'`

Code for @AnkeshKushwah

```
int main()
{
char arr[4]="hell";  
printf("%c",arr[4]); // here you will see garabage. 
printf("%c",arr[5]); // here is the terminating character. after 4.
char arr[]="hell";   
printf("%c",arr[4]); // here you will see terminating character.Because hell will take 
                        0-3 and 4 contains \0 
getch();
}
```

Comment: What? I mean, I can hardly understand the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze in which part you find difficulty in reading.let me know ,i will try to make it clear.

Comment: At first your answer was too short for understanding. Now a good half of it is contained in a single line than one needs to scroll. I don't know if you have a 50" display and it looks fine there, but many people probably don't.

Comment: It's better now, but those `a[20]` and `a[20+1];` are ambiguous. Are those expressions or parts of declarations?

Comment: Then you should've said so. Semi-cryptic answers are hard to understand, especially if you're new to the area.

Comment: ya you are right :). i will remember this `semi cryptic` word while answering the Ques's. ;)

Comment: @Arpit 20 will not used for '\0' it will contain any garbage character, I had the same confusion.
ThankuVM for your efforts and help.......i got this.

Comment: Cause you put the string in char array that's by>>>>
I was talking about this
char arr[20];
cout<<arr[20];
you won't get terminating null>>>>>>

Answer (score 0):

Consider initializing your char array with all zeroes: `char a[20] = { 0 };`

That way, no matter how many chars you write (up to 19), you're always null terminated.

Comment: `char a[20] = { 0 };` initializes the array to all zeroes, which is the same as all null terminators.  You don't have to explicitly write the loop.